# How to add more items to the window context menu

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu

I'm making an app for the company I work for and I was wondering how to customise the window's context menu like PuTTY's (aka, it has "New Session..." etc.). I've looked all over Google and can't find the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: do you mean the system menu ? i  mean the one that pops up when you click the window title bar ?

Comment: when I click the window title bar (The one with "close", etc.)

Comment: okay i've done that once i'll try to recall the method for you, i remember i used winapi to achieve it

Comment: possible duplicate of [need help in windows API InsertMenuItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952343/need-help-in-windows-api-insertmenuitem), [How can I customize the system menu of a Windows Form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615940/how-can-i-customize-the-system-menu-of-a-windows-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a new module and add `Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices` on top

then declare this

```
<Flags()> _
Public Enum MenuFlags As Integer
    MF_BYPOSITION = 1024
    MF_REMOVE = 4096
    MF_SEPARATOR = 2048
    MF_STRING = 0
End Enum

<DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Public Function GetSystemMenu(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, Optional ByVal bRevert As Boolean = False) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Public Function AppendMenu(ByVal hMenu As IntPtr, ByVal uFlags As MenuFlags, ByVal uIDNewItem As Int32, ByVal lpNewItem As String) As Boolean
End Function
```

then on your form load handler add this code

```
Dim sysmenu As IntPtr = GetSystemMenu(Me.Handle)
AppendMenu(sysmenu, MenuFlags.MF_STRING, &H1FFF, "Hello")
```

then, in order to be able to capture the user click on your new menu item, you have to implement this function which will capture all messages, just add it to your form code

```
   Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
      If m.Msg = WM_SYSCOMMAND Then
          If m.WParam.ToInt32 = &H1FFF Then
               ' your menu item is clicked, call a function here
          End If
      End If
      MyBase.WndProc(m)
   End Sub
```

Comment: @GtoXic: this code only adds a new item to the bottom of the menu, i'll edit so you get a solution on how to place the menu item wherever you want

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952343/need-help-in-windows-api-insertmenuitem